# Flutter: call function during scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a scroll controller which checks if the scroll position passed the threshold and then call the function:

```
final _scrollController = ScrollController();
final _scrollThreshold = 200.0;
_scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);

void _onScroll() {
  final maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
  final currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
  if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= _scrollThreshold) {
    dummyFunction();
  }
}
```

Currently, **dummyFunction()** is called multiple times, How to make sure it is going to be called once?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly, but I think you could use `controller.position`, which is the currently visible segment of the scrollable. This variable contains info about its position inside the scrollable, such as `extentBefore` and `extentAfter`. `extentAfter` represents the remaining scroll space available, so you could do something like this to trigger your function:

```dart
  void _onScroll() {
    if (controller.position.extentAfter < someThreshold) {
      _dummyFunction()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `boolean` storing wheather the function was called or not :

```
final _scrollController = ScrollController();
final _scrollThreshold = 200.0;
_scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
final _hasReachedPoint = false;

void _onScroll() {
  final maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
  final currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
  if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= _scrollThreshold && !_hasReachedPoint) {
    _hasReachedPoint = true;
    dummyFunction();
  }
}
```